# How to remove click handler in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

In a page one image control is there.when click on that i am showing big image.in some condition i don't want to show.For that i am trying to remove click handler event.please tell me how to remove image mouse enter click event in wp.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a event handler from a event by using the `-=` operator.

Example for removing a event handler called `OnTap_Handler` from the `Tap` event of a `Image`.

```
Image.Tap -= OnTap_Handler;
```